# Firebase data to tableview, crash after appending data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, append

I am trying to download data from Firebase using

`firebaseDB.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in })`

which works well. I am able to receive the following data:

```
let fetchedObject = items.value as? [String: AnyObject]
let dbUrl = fetchedObject?["url"]
let dbTime = fetchedObject?["time"]
let dbStatus = fetchedObject?["status"]
```

Using `print("\(dbUrl!), \(dbTime!), \(dbStatus!)")`, I see the following output in the console:

> https://google.de, 2019-04-26 07:44:54 +0000, new

However, because I want to show the data in a Tableview, I have created a swift file for a data model, called `ItemModel` with the following content:

```
class ItemModel {

    var url: String?
    var time: String?
    var status: String?

    init(url: String?, time: String?, status: String?){

        self.url = url
        self.time = time
        self.status = status

    }
}
```

When trying to populate the url, time and status using

```
let item = ItemModel(url: dbUrl as! String?, time: dbTime as! String?, status: dbStatus as! String?)
```

appending it with `self.itemList.append(item)`, and reloading the table with `self.tableViewOutlet.reloadData()`, the app crashes.

If I comment out `self.itemList.append(item)`, it does not crash.

What am I doing wrong? I am clearly missing something viable, but I just can't figure out what. I am really wondering why appending the data does not work... Thanks a lot for any help!

**EDIT:**

Complete fetching method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var itemList = [ItemModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        [...]

        // Authenticate user
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() {(authResult, error) in

            if error == nil {

                self.user = authResult!.user // Authenticate User
                self.uid = self.user.uid // Users unique and anonymous identifier by Firebase
                print(">> LOG: Auth success!")

                // Download data from Firebase
                var itemsDB: DatabaseReference!
                itemsDB = Database.database().reference().child("somechild").child("someotherchild")
                itemsDB.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    // Check if there is any relevant data
                    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                        // Initially clear the list
                        self.itemList.removeAll()

                        // Interate through all the values
                        for items in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                            // Get the values from Firebase
                            let fetchedObject = items.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                            let dbUrl  = fetchedObject?["url"]
                            let dbTime = fetchedObject?["time"]
                            let dbStatus = fetchedObject?["status"]

                            let item = ItemModel(url: dbUrl as? String, time: dbTime as? String, status: dbStatus as? String)
                            print("\(item.url!), \(item.time!), \(item.status!)")
                            self.itemList.append(item)

                        }

                        // Reload the Tableview
                        self.tableViewOutlet.reloadData()
                    }
                })

            } else {

                print(">> LOG: Error when trying to authenticate: \(error!)")

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: why you are using this `!` ?

Comment: Which one exactly, @wings?

Comment: The reason why it is crashing because maybe you use this `!` in your item and in your item maybe one of the variable have no value but you force unwrap it so it is crashing

Comment: There are values in the underlying Firebase Database, and they are received properly, as I can see in the console using `print(item.url)`, for example... even if I change the code to `let item = ItemModel(url: dbUrl as? String, time: dbTime as? String, status: dbStatus as? String)`, it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: OK Can you show your fetching method from firebase :)

Comment: Sure! I added to the original question :)

Comment: So your app is crashing when append in itemList

Comment: Exactly… `itemList` corresponds to `ItemModel` (shown above), which is a rather simple one…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192428/discussion-between-wings-and-j-j).

Comment: Okay! :) Thanks a lot already!